# Marcar y desmarcar todos los checkbox en angular 10

Tags: angular, angular5, angular7, angular6

Amigos estoy haciendo un reporte con `checkbox`, obtengo los `checkbox` marcados, pero deseo marcar todos con un `checkbox` general en mi caso de ejemplo frutas

Aquí la imagen del formulario

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

mi component.ts

```
 import { Component, VERSION , OnInit} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular ' + VERSION.major;

  selectedItems:string[];

  ngOnInit(){


this.selectedItems = new Array<string>();
}

getAlbumId(e:any, id:string)
{
    if(e.target.checked)
    {
        console.log(id + 'cheched');
        this.selectedItems.push(id);
    }
    else{
        console.log(id + 'Uncheched');
        this.selectedItems = this.selectedItems.filter(m=>m!=id);
    }

    console.log(this.selectedItems);
}
}
```

Aquí el component.html

```
<hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>
<p>
  seleccione Frutas
</p>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td> <input type="checkbox" > </td>
    <td> <strong>Frutas</strong></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> <input type="checkbox"  name="1" value="false" (change)="getAlbumId($event,'1')"> </td>
    <td>Manzana</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> <input type="checkbox"  name="2" value="false" (change)="getAlbumId($event,'2')"> </td>
    <td>Pera</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> <input type="checkbox"  name="3" value="false" (change)="getAlbumId($event,'3')"> </td>
    <td>Naranja</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[Aqui tengo el codigo en StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-gksytb?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Answer (score 4):

Estructurando los datos de esta manera:

```
datos: Frutas[] = [

  {nombre:"Manzana", checked: false, id: "0"},
    {nombre:"Pera", checked: false, id: "1"},
    {nombre:"Naranja", checked: false, id: "2"},
]
```

Puedes lograr lo que buscas haciendo modificaciones en tu html:

```
<tr *ngFor="let fruta of datos">
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox"  name="1" (change)="getAlbumId($event, fruta.id)"
      [checked]="fruta.checked"
      > 
     </td>
     <td>{{fruta.nombre}}</td>
</tr>
```

Y agregando esta funcion:

```
seleccionarTodo(e:any){

  this.datos.forEach(x=> x.checked = e.target.checked)
  console.log(e)

}
```

Te dejo [un ejemplo funcional](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-z2oxay?file=src/app/app.component.ts).